# Rank of a symmetric matrix after removing a column and row.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have a $n\times n$ symmetric matrix $M$ with real entries, zeros on the diagonal, and two of the column vectors are identical and I remove one of these columns, and the corresponding row, then the rank of our new matrix is equal to the rank of $M$.

I would like to understand why this is true. I understand that removing the column vector alone would not change the rank because we still have the same amount of linearly independent vectors. But it is not obvious to me that the removal of the corresponding row vector would not remove some 'important' entries of the remaining column vectors.

Any help would be great.

Comment: It's a symmetric matrix, so the rows are also identical...

Comment: I understand that. I know rank as the amount of linearly independent column vectors and I am not understanding why it is not the case that removing a row vector might change the fact that no one remaining vector can be obtained by linear combinations of the others.

Comment: I was unaware that rank is also the amount of LI row vectors. Now it is clear. Should I remove the question?